# C++: creating multiple data structures using a for loop

Tags: c++, struct, scope

I have a program where I use records of the form:

```
// declaring a struct for each record
struct record
{
    int number;             // number of record
    vector<int> content;    // content of record    
};
```

Within main I then declare each record:

```
record batch_1;         // stores integers from 1 - 64
record batch_2;         // stores integers from 65 - 128
```

Where each batch stores 64 integers from a list of numbers (in this instance from a list of 128 total numbers). I would like to make this program open ended, such that the program is capable of handling any list size (with the constraint of it being a multiple of 64). Therefore, if the list size was 256 I would need four records (batch_1 - batch_4). I am not sure how I can create N-many records, but I am looking for something like this (which is clearly not the solution):

```
//creating the batch records
for (int i = 1; i <= (list_size / 64); i++)
{
    record batch_[i];   // each batch stores 64 integers
}
```

How can this be done, and will the scope of something declared within the for loop extend beyond the loop itself? I imagine an array would satisfy the scope requirement, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Why not use `vector<record> batch(list_size / 64)` and then init it as needed in a loop? You're already using `vector`s.

Comment: "I am not sure how I can create N-many records". You have used `vector` in the definition of your record. How would you define its function?

Answer (score 2):

Like many suggested in the comments why not use a resizable vector provided by the C++ Standard Library: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

**So, instead of having this:**

```
record batch_1;         // stores integers from 1 - 64
record batch_2;         // stores integers from 65 - 128
.
.
record batch_n          // Stores integers x - y
```

**Replace with:**

```
std::vector<record> batches;

//And to create the the batch records
for (int i = 1; i <= (list_size / 64); i++) {
    record r;
    r.number = i;
    r.content = ....;
    batches.push_back(r); 
    // You could also declare a constructor for your record struct to facilitate instantiating it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this

```
    // code 
    vector<record> v(list_size / 64);
    // additinal code goes here
```

Now,you can access your data as follow

```
    (v[i].content).at(j);
```